# Convergence of random variables and those density functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X$ be random variables $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_1, f_2, \dots, f$ be those density functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$X_i(E) = \int_E f_i d\mu$$

Does the convergence of $X_1, X_2, \dots$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, i.e. $\int_\Omega|X - X_i|^pdP \xrightarrow{n\to \infty}0$, mean the convergence of $f_1,f_2,\dots$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: There is no reason why $f_i$'s have to be in $L^{p}(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What is a good space for $f_i$'s? Or, under what condition $f_i \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Remark $\int |X|^p dP = \int |x|^p f(x) dx,$ so no relation apriori between the integral of $|X|^p$ and that of $|f|^p.$